# Can anyone explain why address operator is returning string and not the address in the following C++ program?

Tags: c++, string

The C++ code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string b="ash";  //string declared 
   cout<<&b[0]<<endl;  //trying to print address but actually what is printed is ash.How??
   cout<<&b[1]<<endl;
   cout<<&b[2]<<endl;
}
```

The output of the following code is as follows:-

```
ash
sh
h
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: `cout` is designed to print `char` pointers as strings. The rest is basic pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Do you know anything about "old-style" C strings, also known *null-terminated byte strings* or "pointers to `char`" (i.e. `char *`)?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a operator to get the address of the variable.

- `&b[0]` gets the starting address of `b[0]` i.e  `a` and returns `ash`.
- `&b[1]` get the address of `s` and returns `sh`.
- `&b[2]` get the address of `h` and returns `h`.

Comment: But isn't a is value at b[0]..How can address be a...Kindly clarify.

Comment: Because b is a string array. The value in b[0] is a char. The address is the part of string b.